# How to check validation of TextField on Button Tap (not by using NavigationLink) in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to validate that my TextField "username" and TextField "password" are not empty before pushing to next screen. Is it possible in SwiftUI?

Example I do this in Swift:-

```
@IBAction func btnSignInTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if (String.isStringEmpty(aString: getString(anything: tfUserName.text))) {
        //Error message
        return
    } else if (String.isStringEmpty(aString: getString(anything: tfPassword.text))) {
        //Error message
        return
    } else {
        //Push screen
    }
}
```

Similarly how can I do that in SwiftUI?

Comment: if tfUserName.text.count == 0 { show error }

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik I want to check in SwiftUI, and in SwiftUI we don't get reference of TextView.

Answer (score 4):

It's easy to do once you embrace the "declarative" nature of SwiftUI. Here's a Swift playground showing a very barebones approach:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport


struct ContentView : View {

    @State private var email: String = ""
    @State private var password: String = ""

    private var validated: Bool {
        !email.isEmpty && !password.isEmpty
    }

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            TextField("email", text: $email)
            TextField("password", text: $password)

            if validated {
                Button("Login") {
                    print("Logging in")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView())
```

Basically you don't work on the `TextField` but on the `@State` and instruct the UI to show the button only when the conditions are met.

Of course, if the validation is more complex than what we have here you may want to use a View-Model object instead.